# Convert CSV file to XML then FTP to server periodically

Tags: xml, csv, ftp

What I'm trying to do and which i can't really find is the following:

I want to periodically (eg: every 5 mins) convert a CSV file into XML either online without me having to do something or downloading the CSV convert it to XML and uploading it again to an FTP server every 5 minutes. I can't really find a program which does that and not really want to write it myself, so maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: If you're looking for an off the shelf application to do this then SO probably isn't the place to ask. If you're looking for programming advice the you need to let us know what languages and frameworks you can use.

Comment: This seems off-topic for Stack Overflow, since you are asking to be handed an application that does what you want. I suggest you try [superuser](http://superuser.com/) instead. _(And clarify what it means to convert a CSV file into XML.)_

Answer (score 0):

Yes this site here does it fairly handy.
http://www.creativyst.com/Prod/15/
Programmatically, try using google app engine or 
use ADO.Net to query the Excel spreadsheet (SELECT * FROM [Sheet1] or whatever) and then just serialise the resulting dataset.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have access to a unix server? I would recommend using shell scripting.